# Excel Index of Bottom Element in Column but > 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have column A that is full of numbers ranging from 0 to 100. How can I get the index of the bottom element, but which is bigger than 0.

For example

```
6
7
9
1
0
8
0
```

In this example the number returned should be "6", as it's the index of the cell that contains "8".

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the array form of MATCH():

```
=MATCH(1E+99,IF($A$1:$A$7<>0,$A$1:$A$7))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This will find the last number in the range that is not 0.

[image]

---

If your list is not static, the list changes length, then you can use this formula which will grow and shrink as the data in column A changes:

```
=MATCH(1E+99,IF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))<>0,$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))))
```

It is still an array and being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Array formula's calculations are exponential and therefore we want to limit the size of the dataset being tested to the extents.  The two `INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` find the last cell in Column A with a number and sets that as the last cell in the range.

[image]

Comment: How can I scale this to 100, 200, 300 elements? What does the "1E+99" mean?

Comment: `1E+99` is a 1 with 99 0s after it. The match is looking for that number if it does not find it, which I would hope it does not, it will return the last number in the set.  You will need to set this to the extents of the data.  Just change both the `$A$1:$A$7` to your data set.

Comment: @askernoob6 see edit for an alternative that is more dynamic.

Comment: @askernoob6 remember that if this helps to mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  If it does not work feedback is appreciated.